# Use feh to open graphviz (dot) files

Tags: graphviz, dot, mageia

in past, I used feh to open directly the *.dot files (from Graphviz), which was great, as I didn't have to convert each *.dot file to jpg/pdf individually in order to display them (although, I imagine that it must have done it automatically there). I often get generated a lot of DOT files in different folder. However, after reinstalling my OS (Mageia), it stop working. I guess, normally feh is not supposed to open dot files, however, I got used to it. I know I could have written a script which would convert DOT to PNG in a tmp directory and open it with feh. However, does anybody know how to do it directly with feh (as I did in past)?
Now, if I type:

`>feh graph.dot
feh WARNING: graph.dot - No Imlib2 loader for that file format
feh: No loadable images specified.
See 'man feh' for detailed usage information`

So my question is rather how to include support for dot files into the Imlib2 loader?

Thanks a lot.